# display tooltip with true dbgrid in vb6

Tags: vb6, tooltip, dbgrid

I need to display a tooltip in a specific column of a true dbgrid. Is there any way to do this? I'm working in vb6. Thanks in advance.

Giampaolo

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved setting the celltips property of the grid to 1 and then implementing the FetchCellTips event of the grid the grid.